# How to send array of bytes from C++ to python with boost python and return it modified?

Tags: python, boost-python, cairo

I am creating small GUI system and I would like to make my rendering with python and cairo and pystacia libraries. For C++/Python interaction I am using Boost Python but I am having troubles with pointers.

I have seen this kind of question asked few times but didn't quite understand how to solve it.

If I have a strcut/class with only pointer for image data:

```
struct ImageData{
    unsigned char* data;
    void setData(unsigned char* data) { this->data = data; } // lets assume there is more code here that manages memory
    unsigned char* getData() { return data; }
}
```

how can I make this available for python to do this (C++):

```
 ImageData myimage;
 myimage.data = some_image_data;
 global["myimage"] = python::ptr(&myimage);
```

and in python:

```
 import mymodule
 from mymodule import ImageData
 myimagedata = myimage.GetData()
 #manipulate with image data and those manipulations can be read from C++ data pointer that is passed
```

My code works for calling basic method calling of passed ptr to class. This is probably basic use case but I haven't been able to make it work. I tried shared_ptr but failed. Should it be solved using shared_ptr, proxy class or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here with the locality of your variable: myimage will get deleted when you get out of its scope. To fix this, you can create it with dynamic memory allocation and moving then moving the pointer to python:

```
ImageData * myimage = new ImageData();
myimage->data = new ImageRawData(some_image_data); // assuming copy of the buffer
global["myimage"] = boost::python::ptr(myimage);
```

Please notice that this does not take care of memory handling on python. You shall use boost::python::handle<> to correctly state you are transferring memory management to python.